# Save flux of records usung spring data elasticsearch in reactive manner

Tags: elasticsearch, reactive-programming, spring-data-elasticsearch

Please help me to find right way to save flux of entities, resceived from Cassandra, to Elasticserch.

For exaple I  have huge flux of entyties:

```
Flux<User> user = cassandraService.getUsers();
```

How can I save all flux of entyties to Elasticsearch using reactive way?
Which method for calling Elasticksearch is better to use:

- user.map(u-> reactiveElasticsearchOperations.save(u, INDEX_NAME));
- user.flatMap(u-> reactiveElasticsearchOperations.save(u, INDEX_NAME));
- user.onNext(u-> reactiveElasticsearchOperations.save(u, INDEX_NAME));
- ...something other..
  ??

And how to block until last entity in flux will be processed?

Comment: And one more question:
reactiveElasticsearchOperations.save(u, INDEX_NAME) returns Mono
Have I to block on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, short explanation of `flatMap()` vs `map()`:

- `flatMap()` should be used for non-blocking operations (asynchronous) - in short, anything which returns back Mono, Flux,
- `map()` should be used to transform an object by applying a synchronous function to each item (performed in fixed time).

So if you want to save a document in Elasticsearch you should use `flatMap()` - this is an async operation and its execution time is indeterministic.

When it comes to `doOnNext()`, it is used to add side-effect behavior, triggered when the Flux emits an item, e.g. for logging or some other action that should happen after saving has finished.

**Example:**

```
Mono.just(productDto)
    .map(dto -> new Product(dto.getName(), dto.isAvailable()))
    .flatMap(elasticsearchOperations::save)
    .doOnNext(savedProduct -> logger.info("Saved {}", savedProduct.getProductName()))
    .subscribe();
```

And you do not have to block on `save()`, this is the responsibility of `flatMap()`.